# Alfresco Solr Admin query interface not finding results while NodeBrowser does

Tags: solr, lucene, alfresco

Doing a simple Lucene search in the Admin Console Node Browser like

@ourNS\:customModeID:123456789

returns quite a few results on our system.
Using the Solr Admin query console

```
 https://someserver:8443/solr/alfresco/admin/
```

finds nothing with the same query. Why? What could we be doing wrong here?
Our syntax looks good to me. Using Alfresco 4.0

Also, what does the "@" in the Solr query actually do? I can't find any documentation on what that represents.

Answer (score 1):

Queries entered into the node browser expand short form field qnames, such as `@ourNS:customModeID` to the full representation `@{http://www.our-ns.com/dunno}customModeID` as it is actually stored in the index. The short version is not expanded when you enter the query into the solr admin query interface. Hence the field you are asking for does not even exist.

The "@" has no special meaning for solr or lucene. It is just an ordinary field name character.

Answer (score 0):

It Depend upon the Queries of Alfresco for node browser that actually stored in the index.